# How to disambiguate a call to member that takes a string or parameter list

Tags: c#

I have the following methods:

```
ShowMessage (string text, string caption) {...}
ShowMessage (string formatText, params object[] parms) {...}
```

I would like to be able to make the following calls:

```
ShowMessage ("Display this message in a Message box", "Caption of Message box");
ShowMessage ("Unable to load file {0}", myStringFilename); // Does string.Format using parms
```

The second call generates error CS0121 about an ambiguous call.
Besides renaming the 2nd member is there a way to disambiguate the 2nd call?

Comment: Keep it simple. Just rename-it!

Comment: I believe the reason CS0121 is generated is that you can specify a parameter list this way: ShowMessage ("P1: {0} P2: {1} P3: {2}", 10, myString, "Parameters on the fly!") and the parameter list is automatically constructed and passed the function so I can see that with a single parameter it doesn't know which member to call.  So although the workarounds provided are reasonable I was wondering if there was a C# way to appropriately disambiguate with a simple syntax change.

Comment: @AlanKley: The posted code *does not* generate CS0121.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you provide a *complete* program that actually produces the error that you don't expect?

Comment: @AlanKley: All your comments on all the answers here don’t make any sense. Everyone’s been telling you *there is no compiler error in the code that you have posted*. If you want to receive any useful help, you should at least post something that *actually demonstrates the problem*.

Comment: Something that *might* help - since I don't know what the problem is I'm reduced to guessing here - is to understand an important rule of C# overload resolution: any method applicable in its "normal" form is *always better* than a method with "params" that is applicable in its "expanded" form. See the overload resolution section of the spec for details. Does that help?

Comment: Thank you all that contributed.  I was in the middle of a project and have not been able to return here until now.  I ended up renaming one of the members.  I also, have not been able to reproduce the error message, except if null is passed in as a second parameter (which makes sense).  The workaround was obvious; I posted here to learn something about C# and overloading, which I did!  Not sure the question deserves a down vote (ok, a bit unclear, but useful!) I admit my presentation could have been better. Next time I'll write a stand-alone app instead of coming up with an example on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think to get it to work the way you want, you'll have to change your second call to this:

```
ShowMessage ("Unable to load file {0}", (object) myStringFilename);
```

I don't think the C# has the concept of a 'better' match to your call.  If there's more than one potential match, you get the error you described.

Comment: Wrong answer. Try looking up §7.4.3 Overload resolution in the C# language specification.

Comment: Jonathon, you are correct that the compiler finds both members an equal match and one is not better than the other. I'm seeking something I can do to "help" the compiler choose one over the other.  Your cast is the type of thing I was looking for, which would have worked for C++ but both string and an array list are objects so we're back to square one.

Comment: I know I've run into a scenario like this where adding an explicit cast gave the compiler what it wanted.  If the language spec spells this scenario out, it must have been a generic type inference scenario  I remember having the problem with before.  Glad someone around here knows the spec by chapter and verse :)

Comment: The (object)myStringFilename would be interpreted as the first member of the params array, so I beleive this would work as Jonathan intends.

Answer (score 3):

You can either explicitly create the params array:

```
ShowMessage ("Unable to load file {0}", new[] {myStringFilename});
```

or you might be able to use named params (havent tested it though...)

```
ShowMessage ("Unable to load file {0}", parms: myStringFilename);
```

Comment: Named params is a great suggestion. It helped me when trying to pass an empty list to a method with overloads that all take `params` of different types.

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid I don’t understand your problem. I tried this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void ShowMessage(string text, string caption)
        { Console.WriteLine("1"); }
    static void ShowMessage(string formatText, params object[] parms)
        { Console.WriteLine("2"); }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myString = null;
        object myObject = null;

        // Outputs 1
        ShowMessage("Display this message in a Message box",
                    "Caption of Message box");

        // Outputs 1, too. No compiler error
        ShowMessage("Unable to load file {0}", myString);

        // Outputs 2. No compiler error
        ShowMessage("Unable to load file {0}", myObject);
    }
}
```

and I don’t get error CS0121 about an ambiguous call. I wouldn’t expect one either. It is unambiguous in both cases: if the types match one overload exactly, that overload is used (thus, overload 1 in the second call), and in the third call there is only one applicable candidate anyway.

Comment: In your second call,  the parameter is not a string so it won't match the first Member.  Both members can be called with a single string as a second parameter (see my comment above) which is where the ambiguity lies.

Comment: @AlanKley: I don’t understand what you are trying to tell us. My answer already says all of that. But there is no compiler error.